# Is Listing All Handlers in UML Diagram Common Practice?

Tags: uml, documentation, diagram

I'm at the stage where I have to draw the UML diagram for my software design documentation.

A sample UML diagram snippet that my professor provided look like this: [image: Sample UML]

As you can see there are three handlers in there.  However, for my project, I have about 60 use cases/events.  And my professor have specifically said to "INCLUDE EVERYTHING".

So does this mean I have to clutter my UML diagram with 60 something handler boxes?

I'm not sure what the common practice on this is.  I have tried to reach out to my professor multiple times but I think he might be really busy in a time like this.

Any advice is greatly appreciated as this is due in couple days!

Comment: There are two handlers, not three, because *BuyTrophyHandler* is drawn twice. You have one dedicated class per handler ?

Comment: Have you thought about putting the info in different diagrams? No system, except for the most trivial, can be captured in detail in a single diagram.

Comment: Think about a generic BuyXXXHandler.

Comment: If that's how your software is built then having 60 handlers would be a complete representation of it. Is the aim to be complete, however, or indicative?